# Using $lookup after insert_one()

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have two collections that I need to join together on a specific field, as laid out below:

temp_recipes

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5cf569311c9d440000dd30d6"},
"ingredients":["3 eggs","1/2 cup flour","1/2 cup milk","1 tbsp sugar","3/4 cup butter, divided","1/2 cup sugar","1 1/2 tsp cinammon","1-2 tbsp molasses","1 cup powdered sugar","2 tbsp half and half"],
"recipe_from":"Bob's Burgers",
"recipe_name":"Dutch Baby"
```

media

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5cf56b7f1c9d440000dd30d8"},
"media_name":"Bob's Burgers",
"category":"TV","origin":"American",
"genres":["Comedy","Animation"]
```

I need to join them on the `recipe_from` / `media_name` fields and I'm struggling to get them into my database. The `temp_recipes` collection is filled out using `insert_one()` from a form on the frontend of the website, and I've been trying to use the [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage to join the two collections after the form is submitted, so the collection will look like this:

```
 {"_id":{"$oid":"5cf569311c9d440000dd30d6"},
"ingredients":["3 eggs","1/2 cup flour","1/2 cup milk","1 tbsp sugar","3/4 cup butter, divided","1/2 cup sugar","1 1/2 tsp cinammon","1-2 tbsp molasses","1 cup powdered sugar","2 tbsp half and half"],
"recipe_from":"Bob's Burgers",
"recipe_name":"Dutch Baby",
"category":"TV","origin":"American",
"genres":["Comedy","Animation"]
```

The current setup of my code is below, the form is triggering the `insert_one()` but the fields from the `media` collection are not being inserted into the `temp_recipes` collection:

```
new_recipe = temp_recipes.insert_one(
    {
    "recipe_name": form["recipe_name"],
    "recipe_from": form["recipe_from"],
    "ingredients": flatForm["ingredients"],
    }
    )
temp_recipes.aggregate([
    {
        '$lookup':
            {
            'from': 'media',
            'localField': 'recipe_from',
            'foreignField': 'media_name',
            'as': 'recipe_media'}}
     ])
```

I don't know if things aren't in the right order or if I've made a bigger mistake, if anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great - I'm quite new to MongoDB and pymongo and mostly muddling through!

Comment: Can you add to your question the output of `temp_recipes.aggregate`? Is it empty? And what value does `form["recipe_from"]` have?

Comment: Your comment has actually just helped me realise the issue - I wasn't calling `temp_recipes.aggregate` so it wasn't actually doing anything. I've answered the question with the code I used below!

Comment: Well, that my comment helped

Answer (score 0):

I've just figured this one out - I wasn't calling `temp_recipes.aggregate` anywhere in the code, so I've added [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) to join the two collections in MongoDB. Full code used here:

```
new_recipe = temp_recipes.insert_one(
    {
    "recipe_name": form["recipe_name"],
    "recipe_from": form["recipe_from"],
    "ingredients": flatForm["ingredients"],
    }
    )
temp_recipes.aggregate([
    {
    '$lookup':
        {
        'from': 'media',
        'localField': 'recipe_from',
        'foreignField': 'media_name',
        'as': 'recipe_media'
        }
    },
        {
        '$out': 'temp_recipes'
        }
     ])
```

This has returned the following output to my database in the `temp_recipes` collection:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5d13c86b2f2c8421f8e381d6"},"recipe_name":"Grilled Frank",
"recipe_from":"It's Always Sunny In Philadelphia",
"ingredients":["Spam","Jelly pancake"]
"category":"TV",
"genres":["Comedy"]}
```

Code slightly edited for clarity, but that's what I've figured out!